# Passing parameters to GM_notification(): How?

Tags: javascript, notifications, tampermonkey

I'm using this code in my script:

```
GM_notification("Done", "Test", "https://image.ibb.co/m83AmQ/mp_logo_white2.png", function(){console.log("bob"));
```

However this doesn't really do what I want. Everything works, except that the `console.log` statement is run after the notification disappears, seemingly going against the [documentation](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_notification),
 which tells me that GM_notification accepts 2 parameters OR 4 parameters (AFAIK, I'm a n00b).

It looks like I am using the 4 parameter method, but as it does not have a onclick callback (that is working), I'd **either** like to find a fix for onclick not working  **or** use the 2 parameter method which accepts sub-arguments (? is that what they are called?). It tells me that the details argument can have any of the following properties, and I have no idea what that would look like, and to be honest, I have no idea where to start.

Comment: `GM_notification({title: 'foo', image: 'bar', text: '42', onclick: console.log});`

Comment: Ahhh, I see. I will try this out. Thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to do this with help from @wOxxOm

```
GM_notification({title: 'foo', image: 'bar', text: '42', onclick: console.log});
```

For more info, check this link out: http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_notification